# Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'server name" -ramdomly occuring

Tags: c#, security, ssl, iis-7

We are getting an intermittent error “Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'server name’” while calling one of our services. Not all the requests are failing but some of the requests fails in establish SSL/TLS connection. We see this error only when more users are using the application. If incase of app pool restart, application is working fine for next couple of hours. 
Below is the detailed exception.

Exception Type: System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException
Message: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'xxxxxxxx.com'.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Void HandleReturnMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: mscorlib
HResult: -2146233087

StackTrace Information

---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

3) Exception Information

---

Exception Type: System.Net.WebException
Status: SecureChannelFailure
Response: NULL
Message: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Net.WebResponse GetResponse()
HelpLink: NULL
Source: System
HResult: -2146233079

StackTrace Information

---

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Please help me in identifying the issue.